# Varios problemas a la hora de crear un exe usando pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Tengo un script que, al inicio del mismo, importan varios archivos .py situados al mismo nivel que el script principal.

Al ejecutar **pyinstaller --onefile .\script.py**, me genera la carpeta dist/script/script.exe pero al ejecutarlo desde consola, me arroja de inmediato un error indicando que no encuentra el módulo:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module_indicators'
```

He probado a lanzarlo sin la opción --onefile, pero el resultado es el mismo. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module_indicators'

He visto soluciones modificando el fichero .spec, pero cada vez que yo lo modifico y vuelvo a lanzar pyinstaller, lo primero que hace es reescribir el fichero y luego lo analiza y carga los parámetros según los ha reescrito, no los que yo había configurado.

Este es el fichero .spec

```
a = Analysis(
    ['bot.py'],
    pathex=["."],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    [],
    exclude_binaries=True,
    name='bot',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
coll = COLLECT(
    exe,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    name='bot',
)
```

Yo modifico el parámetro **pathex**

Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resuelto al final.
Es tan simple como que al llamar a pyinstaller, en vez de pasar como parámetro el nombre del script .py, le pases como parámetro el nombre del fichero .spec

pyinstaller script.spec

Y con esto, en vez de crear su propio fichero spec, usa la configuración que tú le hayas puesto en ese fichero, incluyendo carpetas y demás opciones.